# Autorole with rules screening

Tags: discord, discord.js, rules

I have a Discord.js bot, I want it to give new members a role.
I know how to do that HOWEVER I also have rules screening enabled, and as the option states that giving new members a role will completely bypass the rules screening.

How can I give a role automatically WITHOUT skipping rules screening?

Comment: I don't think this is possible as of right now, as you said above, Discord disabled this.

Comment: This is possible, I went through the trouble of making a new Discord account and Gmail, and realised that I have no roles, but when I click the submit button in rules screening, Bloxlink gives me the unverified role, which means that the Bloxlink developers figured out how to do this. I may contact them or just listen for the unverified role getting added and handle it like that

Answer (score 1):

There is an optional `pending` property on Guild Member Objects you can use for checking.
`true`: Has not accepted
`false`: Has accepted
If `pending` isnt on the object, assume `false`.

---

This can be found on the [discord dev docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#guild-member-object)

The description of `pending` is

> whether the user has not yet passed the guild's Membership Screening requirements

There is also a second note regarding the "optional" nature.

> In `GUILD_` events, `pending` will always be included as true or false. In non `GUILD_` events which can only be triggered by non-`pending` users, `pending` will not be included.

Which effectively means, if you're given a guild member object, check the value of `pending`. If it's not there, assume false.